# How to get and pass the key in another API in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I have an application wanted to implement this scenario in Postman - where i have to create and get the Key and pass the same key to another API to delete

Comment: Request your key, then use that key in your next call.

Comment: Am new to Postman. Can you elaborate ?I have to pass the same Key as part of the URL - not in params

Comment: hey @raja can you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the token/key in your response body of the first request, set it into an environment variable in Tests section like this.

`var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("AccessKey", body[accessKey]);`

After that you can use it in your next request URL as

`http://your-api-endpoint/{{AccessKey}}`

Comment: @elssar Thanks... This is working am able to pass the key

Comment: @raja could you make this answer acceptable as the best one

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have an endpoint to generate your key, like a login post request which returns your user information and token.

Do you have something like that? Let me show you how this could be done:

[image]

After that you get this key/token and use it in the Header tab to send this value in your next request. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have been doing like this.All my tests are in Collection - Now i want all of them to run automatically[I don't want to enter manually everytime]